# A good textbook on Neuroscience

Tags: neuroscience

I want to start learning Neuroscience. Can someone give me an advice about a nice textbook for beginners? I'm particularly interested in the application of Neuroscience in programming and AI development. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is too open-ended.  As an aside, it sounds more like you are interested in artificial neural networks, anyway.

Comment: Artificial and biological neural network share only the name... Understanding, say, how a neuron fires an action potential, would not really give you any advantage if you are just interested in AI. On the other hand, there are tons of interesting computational neuroscience problems, which instead require deep understanding of biological processes, but are not necessarily related to AI.

Comment: "Principles of Neural Science" by Kandel and Schwartz. That was my introductory textbook for neuroscience at Berkeley.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in computational neuroscience, I recommend Dayan and Abbott's book: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/0262541858/ref=redir_mdp_mobile/181-1988504-8834745](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262541858). This is not a book on neuroscience, not AI, although this particular book has more math than the other introductory neuroscience textbooks I've seen.